# Can I change a hyperlink and CSS using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I want to set a CSS id to a different one when a user clicks a tab.

I have all of my divisions as the layout for the site):

```
<a href="page.html"><div id="something"></div></a> <!-- this is one of my navigation tabs that I'll click on -->
```

I want to modify this navigation tab:

```
<a href="page2.html"><div id="something2"></div></a>
```

I want to change the division id to "something3" (and that "something3" is already defined in my CSS)

Also, I want to change the link to "page3.html" (already existing in my folder).

So my question is, how do I change both of those things using javascript?

I already have:

```
function changeTab () {
    if (document.getElementById('something').clicked)
    {
        // change the css and link
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone would help out.

Comment: You could, but rather than change the id I think you would be better off changing a class and keeping the id the same. I would also suggest you attach a click event to the <a> tag as you will find it easier to update the href attribute that way to link to a different page. Some people might shout at me for this, but I suggest you look at http://jquery.com for what you want to achieve as it would be fairly easy to do and there is great documentation. It doesn't look like you know too much about javascript so I would suggest some further reading as well

Comment: You say you want to change the link as well. Did you want to stop it navigating to page2.html and instead go to page 3? Or did you want to open page2.html in a new window and then update the link?

Comment: Stop it navigating to page2.html and instead go to page3.html, as well as change it to the appropriate CSS (div id "page2" to div id "page3").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding an id to your  elements and using classes to achieve the styling on the div. Then you can do something as follows:

```
   //html
<a href="page.html" id="link"><div id="something">something</div></a> <!-- this is one 

    window.onload = (function(){
        var link = document.getElementById('link');
        link.onclick = (function(e){
          if(!link.href.indexOf('page2.html')){
         //continue as normal? 
}else{
           e.preventDefault();
           var childDiv = this.children[0];
           childDiv.id = 'something2';
          link.href= '/page3.html';
            //window.location = '/page3.html'; //uncomment this line to navigate to new page or use window.open to open a new page
}
        });
   });
```

(though I'm not changing the class here but the id as per your request)

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nQr4p/

Comment: Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: If you change the page the styles won't be updated when you return to the original page as it's happening for the user, not changing what your server renders. Also how do you mean simpler? If you look at http://jquery.com like I suggested above you might be able to work out what you need to do

Comment: jquery is something I'm not familiar with. Also, I'm trying to make my site work offline. I may or may not put it online later.

Comment: I've added the href attribute as per your comment above. jQuery is a javascript framework. You can have a local reference to it so it would work offline

Comment: Okay, I got the css to work (I scratched the if statement from the method, put the actions in, and then onClick="method()"). What about the link? I can't do document.getElementById(); now.

Comment: For the link, in your function  try this.parentNode.href = '/page3.hmtl';

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27115/discussion-between-macosx-iam-and-tommybs)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('something')
el.id = 'something3';
el.href = 'newpage.html';
```

But changing `id` of an element it's usually cause of bad design, better use classes for that.

Comment: it doesn't work. When I click, it doesn't reroute to another page and doesn't change the css. Maybe .clicked is not the right condition?

Comment: Macosx Iam you're not attaching you clicked handlers correctly in your code in the question. Also if you click and go to a new page then move back, the styles will be as they originally were. If you go to a new page on a click people won't see your id/style change

Comment: Well, what I want to achieve is when the tab is clicked on, the div id is changed and the link (a href) is changed. How would I do that?

Comment: I got the css to work. Now the link?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var targetLink = document.getElementById('yourLinkObjId') // both elements should be givn ids 
  var targetDiv = document.getElementById('yourDivObjId')
  targetLink.href ='page2.html
  targetDiv.id = 'something2'
```

these should all be placed inside your change function